# Описание условий задач

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Помогите пожалуйста понять что требуется в задачах. В первом примере я не понимаю как вычислить и что за целочисленная точка x. Во втором я не понимаю откуда взять многочлен r, а из-за этого вообще не понимаю как это решить.

> Необходимо описать тип данных, соответствующий предложенному  представлению многочленов, а также разработать следующие функции и процедуры для работы с этими списками-многочленами:
>
> - функцию Meaning(p, x), вычисляющую значение многочлена в целочисленной точке х;
> - процедуру Add(p,q,r) вычисления суммы многочленов q и r, результат – многочлен  p.
>
> Примеры списков-многочленов:
>
> ```
> P(x)= 7x^4 + 3x^2 - x + 2; Q(x)=-2x^5 + 2x^3 + x - 6.
>
> P(x)= -8x^7 - 5x^4 + x + 6; Q(x)=3x^4 + 5x^2 + x - 5;
> ```

Comment: "Meaning"? Значение, что ли? `Value(...)` Не разумнее ли было бы задать эти вопросы тому, кто дал Вам это задание?

Comment: @Igor да, разумнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"целочисленной точке х" - `х`, вероятно, должен быть целым числом.

"тип данных" - массив (или список) коэффициентов многочлена, степень многочлена - количество элементов минус один.

в `Add` - первые два параметра (`p` и `q`) - многочлены (то есть массивы их коэффициентов) которые надо сложить, третий параметр `r` (result) массив коэффициентов результата (получившегося многочлена)

```
P(x)= 7x^4 + 3x^2 - x + 2; - p = { 2, -1, 3, 0, 7 }
Q(x)=-2x^5 + 2x^3 + x - 6. - q = { -6, 1, 0, 2, 0, -2 }
P(x)= -8x^7 - 5x^4 + x + 6; - p = { 6, 1, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, -8 }
Q(x)=3x^4 + 5x^2 + x - 5; - q = { -5, 1, 5, 0, 3 }
```

```js
function Meaning(c, x) {
  var powerX = 1;
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    result = result + c[i] * powerX;
    powerX = powerX * x;
  }
  return result;
}

function Equality(c1, c2) {
  if (c1.length != c2.length)
    return false;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    if (c1[i] != c2[i])
      return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

var p1 = [ 2, -1, 3, 0, 7 ];
var p2 = [ -5, 1, 5, 0, 3 ];
var p3 = [ 2, -1, 3, 0, 7 ];

console.log(Equality(p1, p2));
console.log(Equality(p1, p3));

console.log(Meaning(p1, 3));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59791/discussion-on-answer-by-igor---).